Sharing personal files asks password for user "Please login as the user guest"
I think I successfully enabled personal file sharing over LAN on machine A according to official documentation (22.04 LTS). I also set a password for the share. That share appears on machine B. But when I try access it I'm prompted for username and password for user named "Please login as the user guest". I cannot bypass it but if I try anything then it asks for another password. This is very confusing. What should I do to see the shared folder on machine B?



I figured it out by trial and error. This is either a bug or undocumented feature. But the required username seems to be "guest" and the password should be left blank. The next password prompt is for the share and there you should input the password you set in the sharing setting on machine A.
The share itself still doesn't work and gives weird errors depending on how I try to access it. It also disappears completely when I log out on machine A. I will post a new question about those.
